# regex or string parsing

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse a string which has a specific pattern. An example valid string is as follows:

```
<STX><DATA><ETX>
<STX>A?123<ETX>
<STX><DATA><ETX>
<STX>name!xyz<ETX>
<STX>age!27y<ETX>
<STX></DATA><ETX>
<STX>A?234<ETX>
<STX><DATA><ETX>
<STX>name!abc<ETX>
<STX>age!24y<ETX>
<STX></DATA><ETX>
<STX>A?345<ETX>
<STX><DATA><ETX>
<STX>name!bac<ETX>
<STX>age!22y<ETX>
<STX></DATA><ETX>
<STX>OK<ETX>
<STX></DATA><ETX>
```

this data is sent by device. All I need is to parse this string with id:123 name:xyz, age 27y.

I am trying to use this regex:

final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(.*?)", Pattern.DOTALL);

this does output the required data :

```
<ETX>
<STX>A?123<ETX>
<STX><DATA><ETX>
<STX>name!xyz<ETX>
<STX>age!27y<ETX>
<STX>
```

How can I loop the string recursively to copy all into list of string.
I am trying to loop over and delete the extracted pattern but it doesn't delete.

```
    final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<DATA>(.*?)</DATA>", Pattern.DOTALL);// Q?(.*?)
    final StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(frame);
    final Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(buff);
    while (matcher.find())
        {
            final String dataElements = matcher.group();
            System.out.println("Data:" + dataElements);
        }
    }
```

Are there any beter ways to do this.

This is the output I am currently getting:

```
Data:<DATA><ETX><STX>A?123<ETX><STX><DATA><ETX><STX>name!xyz<ETX><STX>age!27y<ETX><STX>   </DATA>
Data:<DATA><ETX><STX>name!abc<ETX><STX>age!24y<ETX><STX></DATA>
Data:<DATA><ETX><STX>name!bac<ETX><STX>age!22y<ETX><STX></DATA>
```

I am missing the A?234 and A?345 in the next two matches.

Comment: **PACK** ??....and what do you want to do with that string..your question is unclear..

Comment: How could the pattern `(.*?)` applied on the string you provided return such an output? This is really unclear. Try to apply the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) concept.

Comment: I am trying to parse that string....and get the respective values like id: 123, Name: xyz , age: 27y. for all the data blocks that are available.

Comment: Agree there is something fishy in the code and samples you have pasted.  But none the less, there is no need to delete from the buffer, or even have the buffer. Just create `regex.matcher(frame)` then collect the dateElements into a Collection<String> as you loop.

Comment: I tried to do the same. It finds only the first one then doesn't find others.

Answer (score 0):

I really dont know what exactly you want to achieve by this but if you want to remove the occurances of that pattern this line:

```
buff.toString().replace(dataElements, "")
```

doesn't look good. you are just editing the string representation of that buff. You have to again replace the edited version back into the buff (after casting).

Answer (score 0):

Using this regex solves my issue:

```
<STX>(A*)(.*?)<DATA>(.*?)</DATA>
```